# How to duplicate form control's checkbox in Excel 2007 with "TRUE" "FALSE" text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

For example I made check box in **A1** with "=$B$1"
So now, when I click it the "**TRUE**", "**FALSE**" text appears
depending if check box is checked or not.

The problem starts when I want to duplicate those two to
more rows. Now every check box makes the **B1** text to change, not
the one it represents as in check box **A1** should change **B1** text,
check box in cell **A2** should change **B2** text and so on, but now
all check boxes change the same **B1** text.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: How did you create the check box and how did you control it? If you copied the check box, it is exactly that; a copy with the same properties. A little more information will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be partly due to the absolute position you are using when defining your checkboxes.  The dollar sign in the formula means that when the formula is moved to other cells, the "dollared" value will not change relative to the new location.  It's absolute.

Define the checkbox in A1 as "=$B1".  Now when you duplicate to A2, the formula there should become "=$B2".